# return values of selected row into a metadata file

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to return the values row that is selected within a spreadsheet?  We would like to have the ability to have a user select a row in a spread sheet, activate our application, and the values from that row are spit out into some sort of metadata file that we can read.  Is this possible to do or is there something like this that we can modify to work for our application?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the data from currently selected cells in a spreadsheet is relatively straightforward in Apps Script. For a container-bound script attached to the spreadsheet in question, you can do the following:

```
function getSelectedData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // returns the Spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();         // returns the active Sheet
  var selected = sheet.getActiveRange();   // returns the selected Range
  var selectedData = selected.getValues(); // returns a 2D Object array of cell data
  Logger.log(selectedData);                // Writes the data to the Log
}
```

Once you have the values, you can send or write those values wherever you need.